# autoremove deleted Plesk. Can I reinstall it and keep all previous setup?

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

following a few issues, php has been removed using "apt-get autoremove" to be reinstalled. Now, of course, Plesk has been removed as rely on PHP. Such a rooky mistake

anyway

we have a dozen of sites and databases setup through plesk on this server. So here are the questions

- as running

  /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/autoinstaller --select-product-id plesk

run with an error (as plesk is removed...) is there a way to reinstall plesk keeping all the existing configuration files and serial?

- if not, what would be the manual process to setup database and domains manually? as MySQL was running through plesk, we dont have an admin user for MySQL to manage the DBs...

let me know if you need anymore information on this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that this KB article would be useful for restoring damaged Plesk - http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/112699